# Ruby On Rails: how to submit a hidden form automatically every time I refresh a page (no buttons)

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, form-for, hidden-field

thanks to whoever will help me!

I'm currently getting the coordinates of my user every time he enters in a specific page , and I'm trying to store these coordinates updating the user model, that has the fields "latitude' and 'longitude' in it.
Currently it works if the user press the button "I'm here", I'm trying to auto-submit the form and hide the button, but I'm not having success.
To be clear, I'd like that every time someone enters this specific page, his user model will be updated with the new "latitude" and "longitude" without him doing anything or seeing anything.

*the $("#new_coordinates").submit() where "new coordinates" is the form id is currently not working, that's why the f.submit with the button is still there.

Here's my code

```
<p id="geoloc"></p>
<script>
    var x = document.getElementById("geoloc");

    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getCoordinates);
        } else {
            x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }
    }

    function getCoordinates(position) {
        var new_latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var new_longitude = position.coords.longitude;

        $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#latitude_field").val(new_latitude);
                    $("#longitude_field").val(new_longitude);
                    $("#new_coordinates").submit();


                }
        )
    }

    getLocation()


</script>

<%= form_for(current_user, :id=> "new_coordinates") do |f|  %>
    <%=f.hidden_field :latitude ,:id=> "latitude_field" %>
    <%=f.hidden_field :longitude ,:id=> "longitude_field" %>
    <%=f.submit "I'm here", class: "btn btn-small btn-primary jsbuttons"%>

<%end%>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make ajax calls to controller to update the user data. Just consider i want to update the user data when the page loads, `you can use jquery method` `.ready`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.ajax({url: "/update_user", type: "POST", data: {name: "xxx", id: 5});

});
```

In case you want to go with javascript, use

```
        <body>
        HTML Content
        <script>
            (function() {
           $.ajax({url: "/update_user", type: "POST", data: {name: "xxx", id: 5});             
        })();
        </script>
        </body>
```

Also, you have to add the '/update_user' in routes.rb to handle the requests to reach the respective action in controller.

Update:

Once you receive the values in controller

users_controller.rb

```
def update_user
  #you receive all the data in params
end
```

use the params to retrieve the data and use accordingly. params is a hash and you can access the data from keys. Then you can pass those values directly to the method as you want. If you want it something like on the model just to access, you can go with attr_accessor. Read about that though i don't feel you really need that.

Just read the params in action and pass the values accordingly.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I'll try to do that, but I just realised that I don't really need to update them in the model, I mean, in a page I use the method

post.distance_to (current_user.latitude, current_user.longitude) to evaluate the distance between an user the made a check-in somewhere and the current_user.

But I could just use the position.coords.latitude and position.coords.longitude without having the fields in the user model.
But how can I use them in a rails method? Currently I can retrieve them with the javascript id but I wouldn't know how to call them in the distance_to method

Comment: so as i understand, you want the values to be passed on server and just use it to compute accordingly. please confirm and i'll update my ans accordingly

Comment: yes, I realised that I just need to make Rails know those values that I retrieved with position.coords.latitude and position.coords.longitude so that I can call the method post.distance_to(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude).
So i don't need my attributes in the user model anymore!
Sorry if I completely changed the topic of the question, I just realised that.
Thanks again

Comment: To be completely clear:

I have a Distance_To Method that works like this: post.distance_to (latitude, longitude)
I retrieved the latitude and longitude of my current_user with the script of my original question.
I'd like rails to know what those position.coords.latitude and longitude are so that I can call my distance_to method on those values.
Thank you!

Comment: see my updated answer, print params in that action in controller and see the data received. Read it and pass accordingly

Comment: thanks again! but I don't think I understood your answer: If I decided to erase the attributes 'latitude' and 'longitude' from the user model, why do I need an udpate_user method in my user controller?
I mean, there is no way to just use those values that come out from the script and use those to calculate the distance in Rails?

Comment: say ignore update_user , but atleast you need one action which is called in the ajax call in which data is passed.

Comment: thanks! I don't know how I should do that, but I'll look for it!